# How do I delete "Other" option in login menu?

Tags: xubuntu

I started learning to code with The Odin Project. I needed to install virtual box and Xubuntu before I started my study. When I set up Virtualox and Xubuntu. I see the "Other.." section beside my username in the login section. How do I delete it?

Login:

[image: login]

Comment: I was looking through all settings and if you look at https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=143806 you will see `greeter-show-manual-login=false # it does not matter whether this is true or false` so it doesn't look like you can remove the `Other...` from showing up.  That will allow you to type in a name or choose if something else has login capabilities.  But it doesn't mean that the Guest account is enabled.